# uib-tabset killing the scope of my input change directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Had a uib-tabset and a directive that wait for a change on an input inside the uib-tabset, this directive is reached but when it has to fire a scope.$broadcast this don't call the function.

View

```
  <uib-tabset active="active">
     <uib-tab>
       <input type="file" class="upload" share-all="" accept="image/*">
```

Service/Directive

```
.directive('shareAll', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
         link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
           $(elem).on('change', function(event) {
            return scope.$broadcast('shareIt', elem);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.$on('shareIt', function(event, file) {
});
```

I saw this (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1553) but understood nothing at all, and this is killing me slowly.

Some thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that jQuery `$` object, elem is already a [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) object (unless you have jQuery, then elem is already an alias for `$`).

you also didn't closed your functions right.

```
app.directive('shareAll', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.on('change', function(event) {
                return scope.$broadcast('shareIt', elem);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here's a demo [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ar0YaonbktStSOgtvo8L?p=preview)